# Is it possible to run webdriverio app tests against AWS Device Farm without uploading the test suite?

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, aws-device-farm

We currently have a suite of webdriverio/appium tests for our react native app, with separate wdio.conf files for local, simulator, BrowserStack etc.

All of the examples I can find for device farm either involve first uploading the test suite as a zip up front, or creating a custom test runner that obtains a selenium grid url from Device Farm and then triggers the wdio command (but I can only see this being used for Selenium, nothing for appium/app testing).

Is it not possible to run tests from my local machine whilst pointing to AWS Device Farm devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with AWS Device Farm, as you have already noticed that they do not have a Selenium Grid for mobile devices. In general for me it has been a huge hassle to get Appium tests to work on AWS using CI/CD - both because of the setup and the inability to easily debug since I can't run the tests locally against their devices. I would advise using another cloud farm service like Browserstack which allows you to target their grid from your local machine

Comment: Thanks, I feared this might be the case! Seems like a missed opportunity, I wonder if this is something they will implement in the future.